# Slow to start an powershell script with no internet

Tags: powershell

I run a Powershell script on a computer that has no Internet connection. But it takes about 30 seconds to start it. How do I solve it?
I have run ngen.

Comment: When I turn off my WiFi and run powershell.exe, it takes the same length of time as with internet. So it's something specific to your situation.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's more general than that. While I think PowerShell is fantastic in many ways, Microsoft has aimed it primarily and system administrators.  I think that serverfault aligns most closely with that audience.

Comment: See Keith's answer about the Certificate Revocation List

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a known issue with certificate revocation list checks and .NET (which PowerShell is built on).  Check out this [post about the .NET issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/7eed95ab-5562-4c48-a81d-7792566da539/).

Comment: I did as they say:
select TOOLS/INTERNET OPTIONS from IE
- select ADVANCED from the new window
- scroll down to SECURITY
- uncheck "check for publishers certificate revocation"

And it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be trying to do a DNS lookup, and waits for it to time-out. I presume it doesn't take ~30 seconds to start on a machine *with* internet connection? You could try setting a bogus DNS resolver on the working machine, and see if it takes ~30 seconds there too.